# PHP - JSON Response for pound symbol displaying as \u00a3

Tags: php, json, unicode, laravel-5.6

I have some data stored in my database with the currency symbol as `£`

When this is output as json I see this converted to `\u00a3` e.g:

```
 return Response::json($data, 200, []);

{
  "salaries": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "\u00a325,000, Per annum"
      },
   ]
}
```

Is there any way to display this as `£`?

Note i'm using chrome as the browser and laravel 5.6 as the development framework.

Comment: Those are equivalent, just in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` into 4th parameter of `Response::json()` to get unescaped unicode characters, Check out the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) for details.

Comment: Yes, according to RFC 7159 section 8.2 and ECMA-404.